# Typescript array reduce accumulator type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm struggling with defining type for accumulator in array reduce method.

```js
  private buildRequestBody(payoutFields: IWithdrawalRequest): ISignedWithdrawalRequest {
    const sortedPayoutFieldKeys = Object.keys(payoutFields)
      .sort() as Array<keyof IWithdrawalRequest>;

    const requestBody = sortedPayoutFieldKeys.reduce((acc: Partial<IWithdrawalRequest>, key) => {
      acc[key] = payoutFields[key] ;
      return acc;
    }, {});

    ...
  }
```

It keeps throwing a typescript error for acc[key]

> TS2322: Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.   Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.

Comment: If you've solved your own problem do you want to post it as an answer instead of just as a comment?

Comment: I struggle to understand the point of your code. You're basically cloning `payoutFields`, right ? why do you bother to sort its properties ? anyway, if you must do this sorting, you could at least use `Object.fromEntries` to replace that old accumulator pattern, which would remove your typing issue altogether and improve efficiency.

Comment: It is one of the most ubiquitous patterns when dealing with payment provider integration. Anyway thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is an ok solution for now:

```js
const requestBody = sortedPayoutFieldKeys.reduce(
  (acc: Partial<IWithdrawalRequest>, key) => {
    (acc[key] as unknown) = payoutFields[key];
     return acc;
  },
{});
```

better than using "any".